# How do I simplify my code?

Tags: ruby

I'm pretty new to Ruby and have come up with this little game. It feels like it's too long but I'm not sure. Is there any way to simplify the if statement inside? Also should I be using while or can I use another technique?

Please forgive me if this is a bad question. I tried my hardest to fix the code before posting it.

```
def win(reason)
  puts "You win!"
  exit(0)
end

def boring(reason)
  puts reason + " Game over!"
  exit(0)
end

puts "Your friend wants to fight now!"


friend_conscious = true
friend_bleeding = false
friend_angry = false

while friend_conscious 
  puts "Do you kick, punch or taunt?"
  print "> "
  response = gets.chomp
  if response == ("kick" || "punch")   && !friend_angry
    puts "You try to hit your friend."
    boring("You lost the fight, you suck!")
  elsif response == "taunt" && !friend_angry
    puts "Your friend is angry!"
    friend_angry = true
  elsif response == "taunt" && !friend_bleeding
    puts "Your friend is too angry, he knocks you out!"
    boring("You lost the fight, you suck!")
  elsif response == "kick" && !friend_bleeding
    puts "Your friend dodges your kick and knocks you out."
    boring("You lost the fight, you suck!")
  elsif response == "punch" && !friend_bleeding
    puts "Your friend is bleeding"
    friend_bleeding = true
  elsif response == ("taunt" || "punch") && friend_bleeding
    puts "Your friend lunges at you, knocking you to the ground."
    puts "He then beats you up."
    boring("You lost the fight, you suck!")
   elsif response == "kick" && friend_bleeding
    puts "You kick your friend in the balls, he falls to the ground"
    win("You won the fight! What a great holiday.")
   else
    puts "Your friend knocks you out."
    boring("You lost the fight, you suck!")
  end
  puts "What's your next move?"
end
```

Comment: `response == ("kick" || "punch")` does not do what you think it does. The expression `("kick" || "punch")` is evaluated first and returns `"kick"` (because the `||` operator returns its first "truthy" operand), so your code is equivalent to `response == "kick"`. What you want is `response == "kick" || response == "punch"`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you can do that would make a big difference for readability and maintainability. First, make this object-oriented. I'm not an OO zealot but I think here it's a good fit. Secondly, move a lot of your logic into methods. This will make the code more readable overall, and it will make it easier to write tests for.

First, let's write a simple class to keep track of your friend's state:

```
class Friend
  attr_writer :conscious, :bleeding, :angry

  def initialize
    @conscious = true
    @bleeding = false
    @angry = false
  end

  def conscious?; @conscious end
  def bleeding?; @bleeding end
  def angry?; @angry end
end
```

You can use it like this:

```
friend = Friend.new
friend.angry? # => false
friend.angry = true
friend.angry? # => true
```

Next, a class to keep track of the game state:

```
class Game
  VALID_MOVES = %w[ kick punch taunt ].freeze

  attr_reader :friend

  def initialize
    @friend = Friend.new
  end

  def play!
    while friend.conscious?
      puts "Do you kick, punch or taunt?"
      print "> "

      response = gets.chomp
      move!(response)
      puts
    end

    win!
  end

  private

  def move!(kind)
    return send(kind) if VALID_MOVES.include?(kind)
    bad_move!
  end

  # ...
end
```

I've put the game loop into the `Game#play!` method. When the player enters a move, the `Game#move!` method is called. `move!` checks if it's a valid move, and if it is, calls the method with the same name using `send`, e.g. if the player enters `"kick"`, the `kick` method (which we've yet to define) is called. If it's not a valid move, the `Game#bad_move!` method is called.

Before we flesh out the `kick`, `punch`, etc. methods, we should put each outcome in its own method. You have five losing conditions, which we'll call `lose_1`, `lose_2`, etc., and one winning condition, `win_1`. There are also two conditions that set `friend.angry` and `friend.bleeding` so we'll make methods for those, too. Here's a start:

```
def friend_bleeding
  puts "Your friend is bleeding"
  friend.bleeding = true
end

def friend_angry
  puts "Your friend is angry!"
  friend.angry = true
end

def win_1
  puts "You kick your friend in the balls, he falls to the ground."
  friend.conscious = false
end

def lose_1
  puts "Your friend dodges your kick and knocks you out."
  lose!
end

def lose_2
  puts "You try to hit your friend."
  lose!
end

# ...
```

As you can see `friend_bleeding`, `friend_angry`, and `win_1` update the state of the Friend object. The `lose_*` methods call the `lose!` method.

Now that we have those methods, let's take a look at your game logic. I took the time to make a table of the different moves and Friend states and their outcomes:

```
move   angry?  bleeding?  outcome
-----  ------  ---------  ---------------
kick   true    true       win_1
kick   true    false      lose_1
kick   false   -          lose_2
punch  true    true       lose_3
punch  true    false      friend_bleeding
punch  false   -          lose_2
taunt  true    true       lose_3
taunt  true    false      lose_4
taunt  false   -          friend_angry
```

When we sort it this way, it becomes clear how to write our `kick`, `punch`, etc. methods:

```
def kick
  if friend.angry?
    return win_1 if friend.bleeding?
    lose_1
  else
    lose_2
  end
end

def punch
  if friend.angry?
    return lose_3 if friend.bleeding?
    friend_bleeding
  else
    lose_2
  end
end

def taunt
  if friend.angry?
    return lose_3 if friend.bleeding?
    lose_4
  else
    friend_angry
  end
end
```

The advantage of these is that they're very easy to read. You might notice that each of these is identical except for the names of the outcome methods that are called, which makes sense if you look at the table: Grouped by "move," the second and third columns are identical.

We could combine these methods into a single, very succinct method, but readability would suffer a lot. We could also turn each into a one-liner with ternary operators, with the same result. I think that this is a good compromise between succinctness and readability.

We also need a `bad_move!` method, but I'm just going to make it an alias of the `lose_5` method:

```
alias :bad_move! :lose_5
```

Finally, we need `win!` and `lose!` methods that end the game:

```
def win!
  puts "You won the fight! What a great holiday.",
  exit(0)
end

def lose!
  puts "You lost the fight, you suck! Game over!"
  exit(0)
end
```

Let's put it all together:

```
class Friend
  attr_writer :conscious, :bleeding, :angry

  def initialize
    @conscious = true
    @bleeding = false
    @angry = false
  end

  def conscious?; @conscious end
  def bleeding?; @bleeding end
  def angry?; @angry end
end

class Game
  VALID_MOVES = %w[ kick punch taunt ].freeze

  attr_reader :friend

  def initialize
    @friend = Friend.new
  end

  def play!
    while friend.conscious?
      puts "Do you kick, punch or taunt?"
      print "> "

      response = gets.chomp
      move!(response)
      puts
    end

    win!
  end

  private

  def move!(kind)
    return send(kind) if VALID_MOVES.include?(kind)
    bad_move!
  end

  # Moves

  def kick
    if friend.angry?
      return win_1 if friend.bleeding?
      lose_1
    else
      lose_2
    end
  end

  def punch
    if friend.angry?
      return lose_3 if friend.bleeding?
      friend_bleeding
    else
      lose_2
    end
  end

  def taunt
    if friend.angry?
      return lose_3 if friend.bleeding?
      lose_4
    else
      friend_angry
    end
  end

  def bad_move!
    lose_5
  end

  # Outcomes

  def friend_bleeding
    puts "Your friend is bleeding"
    friend.bleeding = true
  end

  def friend_angry
    puts "Your friend is angry!"
    friend.angry = true
  end

  def win_1
    puts "You kick your friend in the balls, he falls to the ground."
    friend.conscious = false
  end

  def lose_1
    puts "Your friend dodges your kick and knocks you out."
    lose!
  end

  def lose_2
    puts "You try to hit your friend."
    lose!
  end

  def lose_3
    puts "Your friend lunges at you, knocking you to the ground."
    puts "He then beats you up."
    lose!
  end

  def lose_4
    puts "Your friend is too angry, he knocks you out!"
    lose!
  end

  def lose_5
    puts "Your friend knocks you out."
    lose!
  end

  def win!
    puts "You won the fight! What a great holiday.",
    exit(0)
  end

  def lose!
    puts "You lost the fight, you suck! Game over!"
    exit(0)
  end
end

Game.new.play!
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more a code review question.
Nonetheless, here are a few pointers/opinions:

1. `win(reason)` never does anything with `reason`
2. `friend_conscious` is only used for the `while` loop, and never changes. Could get rid of it and simply put `while true`
3. Your statements like `if response == ("kick" || "punch")` are not what you intend. Try `if response == "kick" || response == "punch"`, or even better for multiple matches use a regex: `if response =~ /^(kick|punch)$/`

   - `^` anchors the match to the beginning of the string
   - `$` anchors the match to the end of the string
   - The result is the entire string must match

Otherwise, it's a set of dependant rules that probably don't sit in a much nicer way.

Anything other than kick|puch|taunt ends up with you being KOd

```
if response !~ /^(kick|punch|taunt)$/
    puts "Your friend knocks you out."
    boring("You lost the fight, you suck!")
else
    if !friend_angry
        if response =~ /^(kick|punch)$/
            puts "You try to hit your friend."
            boring("You lost the fight, you suck!")
        elsif response == "taunt"
            puts "Your friend is angry!"
            friend_angry = true
        end
    elsif !friend_bleeding
        if response == "taunt"
            puts "Your friend is too angry, he knocks you out!"
            boring("You lost the fight, you suck!")
        elsif response == "kick"
            puts "Your friend dodges your kick and knocks you out."
            boring("You lost the fight, you suck!")
        elsif response == "punch"
            puts "Your friend is bleeding"
            friend_bleeding = true
    elsif friend_bleeding
        if response =~ /^(taunt|punch)$/
            puts "Your friend lunges at you, knocking you to the ground."
            puts "He then beats you up."
            boring("You lost the fight, you suck!")
        elsif response == "kick"
            puts "You kick your friend in the balls, he falls to the ground"
            win("You won the fight! What a great holiday.")
        end
    end

    puts "What's your next move?"
end
```

You can then go one step further and pull each major section out to its own function, i.e:

```
def process_not_friend_angry(response)
    if response =~ /^(kick|punch)$/
        puts "You try to hit your friend."
        boring("You lost the fight, you suck!")
    elsif response == "taunt"
        puts "Your friend is angry!"
        friend_angry = true
    end
end
```

Making sure your functions are below the declaration of `friend_angry` et al

Comment: A small thing: `/^kick|punch$/` will match `"kickfoo"` and `"foopunch"`. I think you probably meant `/^(kick|punch)$/`.

Comment: I did in fact forget the parentheses